# Overriding linked textframes from a master page

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I'm trying to take a master which have several linked textframes on them, then add text to the first textframe and want it to roll over into the next text frame. To do this, I'm creating a new page, applying the master, then overriding the first text frame. No text is rolling over.

I understand from [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/653546) that overriding will take the textframe out of the 'chain' of links on the master, so, how do I do this? Must I really re-link everything again?

This is the code I'm using with COM:

```
page.AppliedMaster.TextFrames["primary"].Override(page);
page.TextFrames["primary].ParentStory.InsertionPoints[-1].Contents = theContent;
```

where primary is the name of the first text frame at the top of the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is yes, you must override and relink all the linked text frames (NextTextFrame) whilst NextTextFrame is not null!